# Socket.io/ PHP server side

Tags: php, sockets, socket.io

I use socket.io for socket app in my client side.  For the server I use socket library of PHP.

After the handsake, the connection was closed and generated a warning

> failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

```
socket_getsockname($socket_server, $addr, $port); 

while($socket = socket_accept($socket_server)) { 


    $handshake = false;
   if(!$socket){
    print "error \n";
   }
   socket_getpeername($socket, $raddr, $rport); 

   $msg = "Welcome aboard !";
   $length = strlen($msg);

   print socket_read ( $socket , 255 )."\n";
   $error = socket_last_error($socket);
   $error_message = socket_strerror($error);

   if(!$handshake){
       $bytes = socket_recv($socket,$buffer,2048,0);
       list($resource,$host,$origin,$key,$key1,$key2,$l8b) = getheaders($buffer);

       $accept = base64_encode(SHA1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", true));

       $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
                   "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" .
                   "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
                   "Sec-WebSocket-Origin: " . $origin . "\r\n" .
                   "Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://" . $host . $resource . "\r\n" .
                   "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " . $accept . "\r\n\r\n";

        if(socket_write($socket,$upgrade.chr(0),strlen($upgrade.chr(0)))) {
            $handshake = true;
        }
     }
     else{
          if(socket_write ( $socket , $msg,$length)){
             print "Mesg envoyee \n";
           }
     }

     do{
        $read = socket_read($socket, 1080);
        print $read."\n";

        if(socket_write ( $socket , $msg,$length)){
           print "Mesg envoyee \n";
        }
     } while ($read != '');
```

in my server side in PHP

in my client :

```
   var socket = io('http://localhost:4454',{
      agent: false,
      transports: ['websocket']
    });
    console.log(socket);
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.send('hi');
      console.log(socket);
    });

    socket.emit('foo');

    socket.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(socket);
    });

    socket.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    //blocage des reconnection si erreurs
    var attemp = 5;
    socket.on('reconnecting', (attemp) => {
      console.log("I'm sad :(");
      //socket.close();
    });
```

I don't find any solution for this issue.
I don't understand why in localhost  stream was automatically close.
Server side looked fine, in this time...

Comment: use this one: https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io